# Import and Export Wizard errors with SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

I just installed SQL Server 2022 and doing some testing and found that I cannot export any tables using the Import and Export Wizard. Went online and saw one of the CU updates fixed other known issues with the wizard and even through they were not exactly like mine (column conversion issues), I applied the latest CU3 and still have issues. I get the error:

> The data type could not be assigned to the column "SpatialLocation" in Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

I have the same exact AdventureWorks2019 database on my SQL Server 2016 and can run the export no problem to the same destination server so I'm wondering if it's a SQL Server 2022 trying to export to a SQL Server 2016 machine. Anyone else experience this issue?

Installed CU3 to my SQL Server 2022 and trying to use the Import and Export wizard to export a table to a SQL Server 2016.

Comment: What version of SSMs are you using? And what settings are you using for your export?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, this is my first time using this site and didn't see you comment.  My current SQL version is 16.0.4025.1.  I applied CU3.  I'm using the Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server when I use the Export wizard.

Comment: The latest version of SSMS is in the 18.X. I'd suggest trying with a more recent version

Comment: Note:  I was able to run it using the Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server which uses MSOLEDBSQL instead of SQLOLEDB then configure the Data Link Properties to point to Source and Destination. After that it exported the table with no issues.